# How to fix the " there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification " without defined contraint in table

Tags: postgresql

My query :

```html
insert into report_order_control_measure(cm_id,report_type,sort_order,temporal_start_date,temporal_end_date) 
values(2,'WAR',220,null,null) 
ON CONFLICT (cm_id,report_type,sort_order,temporal_start_date,temporal_end_date) DO NOTHING
```

Output

`ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification SQL state: 42P10`

There is no constraint defined in the table . but I would like to throw an error if all the columns in the insert makes a row and exists

Any help to make it work without changing the table properties ?

Comment: The only way to use `on conflict()` is to create a unique constraint. However, given the column names `start_date` and `end_date` I wonder if in reality you want an exclusion constraint over the _range_ defined by those two dates to avoid overlapping ranges

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Any other way to find the avoid the duplicate record insert ?

Comment: The only way to use `on conflict()` is to create a unique constraint (or index)

Comment: NO overlaping of the range is required for dates but  just the dates should not be the same.

Comment: INSERT INTO report_order_control_measure(cm_id,report_type,sort_order,temporal_start_date,temporal_end_date) SELECT 2,'WAR',220,null,null WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM report_order_control_measure WHERE cm_id=2 AND report_type='WAR' AND sort_order=220 AND temporal_start_date IS NULL AND temporal_end_date IS NULL)

Comment: @Yogus: that is not safe for concurrent inserts. The only way to catch duplicates with concurrent inserts is a unique constraint

Comment: Indeed, I was going to add this warning in the answer

Answer (score 4):

Use the `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO report_order_control_measure(cm_id,report_type,sort_order,temporal_start_date,temporal_end_date) 
SELECT 2,'WAR',220,null,null 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM report_order_control_measure 
                 WHERE cm_id=2 
                   AND report_type='WAR' 
                   AND sort_order=220 
                   AND temporal_start_date IS NULL 
                   AND temporal_end_date IS NULL)
```

This is only usable in setups where there are not simultaneous/concurrent INSERTS with the same values.

The only 100% safe way to insert without duplicates in all scenarios is to add a unique constraint.

Comment: You should mention that this is not safe for concurrent inserts. If two transactions do this at the same time, there will still be duplicates in the table.